# Enemies aren't going to individual locations Tower Defence

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Long story short, I have a random map generator for a Tower Defence game. I am having some issues with the wave mechanic. The first enemy in the wave goes from start to exit while still following the road. The rest of them are just following the first one. Here's the code for this:

```
private void MoveOnTheGrid()
        {
            if (pathCells != null && pathCells.Count > 1 && !enemyRunCompleted)
            {
                foreach (var enemy in WaveManager.listOfEnemies)
                {
                    currentPosition = enemy.transform.position;   //enemy.transform.position; 
                    nextPosition = new Vector3(pathCells[nextPathCellIndex].x + 0.5f, 1.5f, pathCells[nextPathCellIndex].z + 0.5f);
                    enemy.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(currentPosition, nextPosition, Time.deltaTime * this.enemy.speed);
                    //enemies.

                    if (Vector3.Distance(currentPosition, nextPosition) < 0.05f)
                    {
                        if (nextPathCellIndex >= pathCells.Count - 1)
                        {
                            Debug.Log("Reached end!");
                            EndPath();
                            enemyRunCompleted = true;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            nextPathCellIndex++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I am sure that the issue is because of the nextPathCellIndex that, once is increased, all of the enemies inside the wave are going to the same location. I have tried using a Dictionary instead of the "listOfEnemies" but I realised it's not really useful.

Any ideas? Cheers!

Comment: You need a destination for each enemy and to turn it to the next one when it gets there

Comment: @BugFinder Can't really make up my mind on how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: Have a list of way points. Have an enemy take a waypoint number when he gets there he gets given the next one and heads there

Comment: @BugFinder I am not having this issue with the first enemy, the first one goes along the pathway in the correct way. The issue is with the rest of the enemies. I have the List<Vector3> pathCells which stores the list of locations which the road is placed on, which arguably is the same as your idea. The real issue is with the "nextPathCellIndex". Once it's increased for the first enemy, it also gets increased for the rest of them

Comment: @BugFinder As an example, if the first enemy has to go from square 3 in the pathway to square 4, the rest of the enemies are also heading towards square 4, instead of going to their individual squares

Comment: Right but you need destination’s per enemy

Comment: @BugFinder agreed. How would you implement that?

Comment: I covered that already. Still in hospital not going to write it for you